# Regex validate with last character

Tags: regex

Having regex patter like this: `ab*d` why does it return match true for input `abbbde` ? How to change it to check also last character ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Lets analyse your regex:

a - match an "a"

b* - match any number of b's

d - match a "d"

Because * matches any number of b's.

$ matches end of line, so

```
ab*d$
```

should match end of line (to make sure nothing follows)

Then again \s will match any whitespace so another option is

```
ab*d\s
```

Comment: ok great, but if I added $ to the end it also check lengh? because now ab*d$ desn't validate abdgdgdgd , I thoght that * means 0 or more any characters..

Comment: * means any number of the preceding character

Comment: so how to do 0 or more any characeters ?

Comment: b+ means 1 or more b's

Comment: any number of any chars = [\s\S]*

Comment: . = any char and *= any amount

Answer (score 8):

You need to add a `$` at the end of the pattern to ensure it is the last character `ab*d$`.

A `$` is called a `End of String Anchor` in Regular Expressions. You can read more on Anchors here http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html